# Setting PATH in /etc/environment and .bashrc has corrupted the system

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables, bashrc, etc

Using Ubuntu 14.04, was trying to set simply JAVA PATH (that is where the saga began) now my system seems totally corrupted.

1. I initially edited the PATH in `etc/environment` (that is where my PATH seems to be) and also added a line `export JAVA_HOME`.

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/jdk1.8.0_111/bin"
   export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_111
   ```

This seemed to work till it did not. It did not work seemingly because of some old versions of JVM that were conflicting/confusing.

2. Based on forum wisdom I edited `.bashrc`

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME= /opt/jdk1.8.0_111
   export  PATH= $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   ```

   Probably there was some syntax error (or something).

Now I am getting all kinds of errors when I open a terminal:

```
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/opt/jdk1.8.0_111': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/jdk1.8.0_111/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_111/bin': not a valid identifier
```

**Note**: Duplicate jdk in path - this likely is because PATH both in .bashrc and environment.

**Now I am unable to find/edit either etc/environment or .bashrc**

```
@ubuntu:~$ sudo gedit /etc/environment
bash: sudo: No such file or directory
@ubuntu:~$ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
bash: sudo: No such file or directory
```

**Fixed this above issue Thanks @muru**

My core problem seemingly is caused by multiple java versions but I have only JAVA version

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
```

My program is not finding `JAVA_HOME`

```
$ sudo service dse start
Java executable not found (hint: set JAVA_HOME)
```

---

```
$ echo JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME
~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
```

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

What do I do now?

Answer (score 2):

```
export JAVA_HOME= /opt/jdk1.8.0_111
export  PATH= $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

These lines should not have spaces after `=`. Use `/usr/bin/gedit ~/.bashrc` and correct these lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_111
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Comment: muru Thnaks. I was able to edit the .bashrc and fix the typos. Now No errors in booting. Also fixed the etc/environment removed the duplicate path there. But was getting errors on terminal

Comment: My core problem of program not finding JAVA (seemingly caused duplicate java version remains) - I have only 1 java version and PATH and JAVA_HOME correctly set I can echo and -version

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `~/.bashrc` is not a good place to add Java folders to `PATH`, since it won't be effective in the graphical environment. I'd try to move those (corrected) lines from `~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile` and relogin.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48978/discussion-on-answer-by-gunnar-hjalmarsson-setting-path-linux-corrupted).